# Exception in hibernate

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

I am trying to develop a dynamic web project in Eclipse. I am using hibernate 3, tomcat 6 . My web page has a simple registration form. It accepts the user data and adds it to the db.
I am using hibernate to do that part.
I am getting this error. Have tried the solutions given in some of the similar questions asked but could not solve the issue.
The error that I get is

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
May 23, 2014 10:20:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet NavigationController threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.pkg.dao.UserDAO.registeruser(UserDAO.java:58)
    at com.pkg.controller.NavigationController.doPost(NavigationController.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 17 more
```

My Customer.hbm.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.pkg.bean.CustomerBean" table="r_customer">      
      <id name="CUSTOMERID"  column="CUSTOMERID" type="String">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>      
      <property name="PASSWORD" column="PASSWORD" type="String"/>
      <property name="CUSTOMERNAME" column="CUSTOMERNAME" type="String"/>
      <property name="CONTACTNUMBER" column="CONTACTNUMBER" type="String"/>     
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And by hibernate config file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:javadb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
             <property name="hbm2ddl.auto"></property>
             <mapping resource="Customer.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Can anyone please help me out solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have empty

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto"></property>
```

Put some value there `update/create`.

Answer (score 1):

The changes that I made to my code to make it work are

In my `Customer.hbm.xml` file
I changed the type of column from `type="String"` to `type="string"`

In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file I had create the table in database already so 
I commented  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

The problem seems to be system specific because the code was working without any hiccups in my home computer but was showing
 `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml` error in my office computer.

At home I am using Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7 and hibernate 3.6.4 Final

In office there is Eclipse Galileo , Tomcat 6 and hibernate 3.x.x

I am not really sure want really solved the problem or the problem crept-in in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `hibernate.cfg.xml` refers to `Customer.hbm.xml`, and that file refers to a class `com.pkg.bean.CustomerBean`. It might not be wrong, but it doesn't follow the conventions, so I suspect there *might* be a problem there:

According to these conventions, `hbm.xml` files would be stored in the same package as their class. If that's the case, probably you should be referencing it as `com/pkg/bean/Customer.hbm.xml`.

Another convention is to name your files with the same name as your `hbm.xml` files. So then it would be `CustomerBean.hbm.xml`.

This is just a guess, based on the information you posted. I am not sure if any of these "conventions" are rules that would cause exceptions if broken (it's been a long time since I read the docs, and I usually follow best practices so I never tested to see what would happen if I didn't).

Comment: Following conventions is always helpful. Found that out the hard way. I will keep that in mind while writing the code.